# Why is the Zero Vector so Big?

Tags: delimiters, vector, height

[The `esvect` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/esvect) seems to produce a zero vector with height larger than I would have expected.

The one shown in red is produced using `$\norm*{\Vec{0}}$` and seems to have the delimiters resized larger than needed.
I can fix it using either:

- `\norm` instead of `\norm*` or
- `\smash{}` as shown in blue,

but wondering why `$\norm*` seems to think that the zero vector has that much height.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}%
\renewcommand*{\Vec}[1]{\vv{\mathbf{#1}}}%
\newcommand*{\U}{\Vec{u}}
\newcommand*{\V}{\Vec{v}}
\newcommand*{\Z}{\Vec{0}}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}}
\tiny\verb|\norm*{\V} |  & 
\tiny\verb|\norm{\Z} |  &
\tiny\verb|\norm*{\Z} | &
\tiny\verb|\norm*{\smash{\Z}} | &
\tiny\verb|\norm*{\U}|
\\
$\norm*{\V}$  & 
$\norm{\Z}$  &
\textcolor{red}{$\norm*{\Z}$} &
\textcolor{blue}{$\norm*{\smash{\Z}}$} &
$\norm*{\U}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure of what you expected: `\norm*` does its job, which is to enlarge the delimiters in order to cover the contents (with a small gap allowed).

Comment: @egreg: I guess I don't understnad why `\norm*` seems to think that `0` has a larger depth?

Comment: When you use `\left` and `\right`, the delimiter is centered with respect to the axis of formulas (the imaginary line where fraction lines sit). Try `$\left[\mbox{\Huge A}\right]$` and you'll see the same effect. One more reason for using `\left` and `\right` very sparingly.

Comment: @egreg: Ok, that explains it then.. I guess I should have known that by now!! Perhaps I should remember have my afternoon coffee before posting questions :-)

Comment: `Why is the Zero Vector so Big?` Beats me. It should be full of zeroes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the package you mention. It's a property of `\left...\right`. The delimiters are centered w.r.t. the math axis, therefore when larger height is needed, the depth is increased accordingly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}%
\renewcommand*{\Vec}[1]{\vv{\mathbf{#1}}}%
\newcommand*{\U}{\Vec{u}}
\newcommand*{\V}{\Vec{v}}
\newcommand*{\Z}{\Vec{0}}


\begin{document}

$\left\|\overline{0}\right\|$ $\norm*{\Z}$

\end{document}
```