# Conventional notation for a vector that is half zeros and half ones

Tags: symbols, vector

I was wondering if there was a mathematical convention for expressing the notion of "a vector which is half zeros and half ones". If you consider the two separately, I guess one could write `$\Vec{0}$` and `$\Vec{1}$`, following the suggestion on [this previous TEX Stack Exchange post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183605/why-is-the-zero-vector-so-big/183606#183606). I'm supposing that my total vector length is `N`.

The best I could come up with was *this*, but I was wondering if there was any better way to get the point across.

[image]

```
\left[\overrightarrow{0}^{N / 2} \ldots \overrightarrow{1}^{N / 2}\right]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Link in your question doesn't work.

Comment: This is actually off topic here, as the question asks for a specific notation, not how to set some given/known notation.

Comment: Thanks @Zarko, I've fixed the link now!

Comment: @Werner, I apologize if this isn't the right venue for this kind of question. I just figure people who set known notations would know more notations than I do. :-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should probably be asked on Math.SE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some comments, observations, and suggestions:

- If you're going to use arrow-type symbols, such as `\overrightarrow`, for vector notation, I strongly recommend employing the [old-arrows](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/old-arrows) package as well. Compare the appearance of the screenshot you posted with that of the first row in the screenshot below. I hope you'll agree that the smaller arrowheads "work" better.
- With your notation, the `N/2` superscripts actually come to lie *below* the `\overrightarrow` symbols. I suggest placing them a bit higher up, to restore the notational hierarchy so to speak. See the second row below.
- A serious drawback of using `\left[` and `\right]` in the present context is that the square brackets can quickly become far too large, typographically speaking. I suggest you employ a `bmatrix` environment (provided by the `amsmath` package). See the third row, and, in particular, observe the welcome decrease in the size of the square brackets. Using a `bmatrix` also allows spreading out the entire expression a bit, by inserting `&` markers on either side of `\ldots`. In addition, I also use a macro called `\Nhalf` to typeset the exponent terms `N/2` more tightly in both the third and fourth rows,
- Fourth: Do consider using `\vec` instead of `\overrightarrow` to denote vectors. The only *input* difference between rows 3 and 4 is that the former uses `\overrightarrow` whereas the latter uses `\vec`; do note how much more compact the entire expression becomes.
- Finally, a full alternative to arrow-type notation: Use `\underbrace` directives to indicate that there are N/2 zeros and ones. See the fifth and final row in the following screenshot. The resulting expression is more "wordy" than the arrow-based notation; the upside is that it is pretty much self-explanatory.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for 'gather*' and 'bmatrix' environments
\usepackage{old-arrows} % for smaller arrowheads
\newcommand\Nhalf{N \mkern-3mu / \mkern-1.5mu 2} % more compact notation
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\left[
  \overrightarrow{0}^{N / 2} \ldots \overrightarrow{1}^{N / 2}
\right] \\
\left[
  {\overrightarrow{0}}^{N / 2} \ldots {\overrightarrow{1}}^{N / 2}
\right]\\
\begin{bmatrix}
  {\overrightarrow{0}}^{\Nhalf} & \ldots & {\overrightarrow{1}}^{\Nhalf}
\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix}
  {\vec{0}}^{\Nhalf} & \ldots & {\vec{1}}^{\Nhalf}
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
\smash[b]{\underbrace{0 \dots 0}_{\text{\tiny $\Nhalf$ times }}} 
\smash[b]{\underbrace{1 \dots 1}_{\text{\tiny\ $\Nhalf$ times}}} 
\end{bmatrix} \vphantom{\underbrace{1}_{N}}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive comparison of all the different arrow methods! Like you said, I think self-explanatory-ness is key, so the underbrace method you mentioned last seems the most easy to understand at super quick glance.

Comment: My eventual goal is to put this as one line within a \begin{algorithmic} context. So I was looking for a notation which was compact but instantly understandable to programmer types. The underbrace method might do that best.

Answer (score 3):

One common notation is to use ISO style:  (`\mathbf{0}`) for the all-zeroes vector and  (`\mathbf{1}`} for the all-ones vector.  The ⧺ operator (`\doubleplus`) is often used for string concatenation, if you treat these as binary strings.

That would be something like, in `unicode-math`,

```
\mathbf{0}^{\frac{N}{2}} \doubleplus \mathbf{1}^{\frac{N}{2}}
```

Another option would be to define an operator that pads a vector with zeroes to the left, e.g. `\DeclareMathOperator{\leftpad}{leftpad}` followed by `\leftpad_N \mathbf{1}^{\frac{N}{2}}`.  If you want to be able to pad with an arbitrary element to width N, the notation might be `\leftpad\nolimits_e^N`.

Another would be to put underbraces below `0, \dots, 0` and `1, \dots, 1` showing that there are N/2 elements within each range.

Comment: Thanks, @Davislor! Your first suggestion with the \doubleplus, and your last suggestion with the \dots, made the most sense to me! Much appreciated.

Comment: Just a heads-up that @Mico has given a super comprehensive answer as well, so I've now accepted their solution. But yours was helpful as well! I'll try out all the different notations here to see what looks best in context.